# Adding version info to a Windows Phone 8.1 C++/CLI Class Library

Tags: dll, c++-cx, windows-phone-8.1

I have created a universal C++/CX windows runtime component library.  Universal library projects in VS2013 build to a Windows 8.1 dll and a Windows Phone 8.1 dll.

For the Windows 8.1 dll I can add a "resource.rc" file, and then add VERSIONINFO to that.

But for the Windows Phone 8.1 dll I cannot add a "resource.rc" file because that requires winres.h, which is not present.  I tried removing all of the references to winres.h from the Resource.rc code, but the resulting dll does not contain the version information.

How do I version a C++/CX WP 8.1 wrc library?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Add .rc file as usually. Then go to project "Configuration Properties > Resources > General".

To "Additional Include directories" add **$(WindowsSDK80Path)\Include\um**.
Basically, it should point to path like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um".

Comment: when adding the resource file, it will not load by default.

the second part mentioned by Nikola is key:
"<right-click phone project> -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Resources -> General -> Additional Include Directories" is where you need to paste *$(WindowsSDK80Path)\Include\um*.  Note that you will have to manually add the VS_VERSION_INFO file (it can be easily copied from your Windows Project).